# Merge several video files with ffmpeg and lose any track

Tags: video, ffmpeg

**How to join two video files without losing any channel with ffmpeg ?**

**Origin**, we have 2 video files ts record with the TV decoder TNT.

**Destination** we would have one single video file containing the same number of channels as each original file.

**Goal :** The resulting video will have the same number of channels that each of the original videos.

**usual command to merge :**

```
ffmpeg -threads 4 -i data0001.ts -i data0002.ts -i data0003.ts -c copy -scodec copy video.ts
```

**Channel information video files :**

```
$ ffprobe data0001.ts -hide_banner
```

give me this type of result :

```
Stream #0:0 : Video: mpeg2video ...
Stream #0:1: Audio: mp2 ...  
Stream #0:2: Audio: mp2 
Stream #0:3: Subtitle: dvb_subtitle 
Stream #0:4: Subtitle: dvb_subtitle
```

Answer (score 1):

the command **-map 0** allows to scan all channels,

the command **"concat:data0001.ts|data0002.ts|data0003.ts"** is safer and avoid errors

the command **-ignore_unknown** prevents conversion errors incorrect channels :

```
ffmpeg -threads 4 -i "concat:data0001.ts|data0002.ts|data0003.ts" -map 0 -c copy -scodec copy -ignore_unknown video.ts
```